# Vertical margin changes on horizontal resize

Tags: css

I can't figure out why my div is losing vertical margin on a horizontal resizing of the screen if the margin I give the div is `margin: 20% auto`. Am I misunderstanding how the percentages work? Below is a demo.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mullty/pen/RxgrZr)

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.main {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  margin: 20% auto;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentage works on the width of the container block, according to the css specifications in `w3.org`

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
>   generated box's containing block.

[Read here in details](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#margin-properties)