# How to properly use the grid to achieve this layout?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

Im using bootstrap  grid and I want to achieve a responsive layout like is in the image below:

[image]

That is, the first layout is for md, lg and xl devices, where there is a image at the left and then some information at right. And this div with informations at right should have the same height of the image.

Then in smaller devices I want to get the layout adapted to the image below, where the image is above and the informations below.

But its not working properly:

- The details div appears at right but i want that this details div occupies the full height of the image and the content occupies also the full height, so im using display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; but the content is not occupying the full height
- The other issue is that in extra small and small devices I want to get the image above the details div, but Im getting always the same layout in all devices.

Do you know how to fix this issues properly?

working example with the 2 issues: https://jsfiddle.net/h4pggx0u/1/

html:

```
<div class="container py-md-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-10 px-0">
      <img style="width: 100%; height: auto" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x400"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-2 px-0" style="border:1px solid gray;">
      <div class="details-title">
        <span class="font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Info</span>
        <h1 class="h5 mb-0 title">Title</h1>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block link">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.details-title{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;


  .title{
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }

  .link{
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your class for small screen which takes full grid i.e `col-sm-12` like this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container py-md-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 px-0">
      <img style="width: 100%; height: auto" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x400"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 px-0" style="border:1px solid gray;">
      <div class="details-title">
        <span class="font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Info</span>
        <h1 class="h5 mb-0 title">Title</h1>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block link">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But do you know why the image and the details right div dont have the same height on md, lg and xl devices?

Comment: @JnK since you have given height as auto so it will depend on width of the screen. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052053/vertical-margin-changes-on-horizontal-resize/48052126#48052126

Answer (score 0):

You already have a perfectly acceptable answer, but I wanted to offer the below code as a minor alternative.  This code relies on a different set of Bootstrap classes to achieve similar results:

- `.img-fluid` replaces the need for your inline styles on the `<image>` in the first column.
- `.no-gutters` replaces the need to override the padding on each column.
- `.col-sm-*` has been replaced with `.col-*` to reflect the smallest possible viewport.
- `.border` replaces the need to have an inline border applied on your 2nd column, albeit it by default significantly lighter.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x400" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2 p-3 border">
      <div class="details-title">
        <span class="font-size-sm font-weight-semi-bold">Info</span>
        <h1 class="h5 mb-0 title">Title</h1>
        <a href="#null" class="btn btn-primary btn-block link">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```